# Facebook open graph api missing feeds

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I use Facebook's Open Graph API to retrieve feeds of specific users by requesting the following:

```
feed?ids=<list_of_comma_seperated_ids>
```

this returns almost all feeds as I see them in Facebook site. however, some feeds (mainly likes on statuses and photos) are missing, although the missing feeds are public and can be viewed by any Facebook user.

These fields also do not get returned when querying stream table using fql.
Is there a way to get those missing feeds?

Thanks

Comment: I have heard people having issue with the Graph API having some feeds skipped, but FQL Should work just fine. Can you post your FQL query in the question?

Comment: Facebook allows users to inhibit apps from reading some of their information. You can see the information in Facebook, but can't get at it through any API calls. See Privacy->Apps->"How people bring your info into apps they use"

Comment: The fql I use is very simple: select <fields> from stream where source_id in(<ids>) and is_hidden=0. with fql I also have an issue where only 3-4 results are returned (without paging). regarding the privacy setting - I also check with a test user which have these settings enabled.